# Need to extract the Data layer infomation from Googe TAG manager using Java / Selenium or by any language- for automation purpose

Tags: java, selenium, google-api, google-tag-manager

I have a website where I enable preview mode and verify the events in Google tag manager. 
I need to extract the event , and event name from the data layer of tag manager. 
Kindly help me out the code in Java or Selenium to optain. I need to automate this functionality
Here is an sample image attached. For security purpose the image is blurred.
[image: TagManager]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could look at https://github.com/google/data-layer-helper 
and at the source code of a few Google Chrome extensions that do audit events and dataLayer values

I would suggest [datasLayer](https://dataslayer.org/) 
https://github.com/sean-adams/dataslayer

And also 
https://www.adswerve.com/tools/adswerve-data-layer-inspector-2/

Very good idea to include dataLayer monitoring in automated QA ! I hope this helps.

Actually, you don't have to be in *debug* mode for these tools to run, but you may want to QA the behavior before pushing changes live then you need *preview* only ?

I suggest that you look at GTM Environments 
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6311518?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for a way to access dataLayer values. I can help you with that in JavaScript.

First make sure that `Container ID` variable is checked under built in variables. If you don't see it, click the configure button.

Then all you need is this line of code

`window.google_tag_manager[{{Container ID}}].dataLayer.get('eventDesc')`

Keep in mind that this code only gives you the last pushed value of eventDesc.

So If this push() is happening each and every time -let's say- a user clicks on a link or makes a selection on a drop down menu, you can only access the last click or selection of the user, however, you can use the event key to catch the values for each push but then you would need different event names for each push.